# Increase price based on percentage Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

The valuta (currency value) of my country (Angola) change almost every day.
It's almost impossible to update the prices of each products manually.

I really want to know if there is anyway to update the price of all the products through the percentage.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I’m using this extension
https://amasty.com/mass-product-actions-for-magento-2.html

It’s rather expensive, but works.

Comment: Thanks Ineluki, but i really want to learn by doing by my self.